# Paper margins with fancyhdr package?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

When I use the `fancyhdr` package, the paper margins stretched and the white space decrease, how can I set the paper margins correctly when using the `fancyhdr` package?

Here is the code,

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 14pt,oneside]{extreport}
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=2cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\parindent=2cm
\sloppy 
\hyphenation{} 
\hyphenpenalty=4000
\exhyphenpenalty=4000
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%\rhead{\nouppercase{\textbf{\textsc{\textsf{\thepage}}}}}
\rhead{}
\lhead{\nouppercase{\textbf{\textsc{\textsf{\leftmark}}}}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyfoot{}
\cfoot{\nouppercase{\textbf{\textsc{\textsf{\thepage}}}}}
\chapter{Bla bla}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Clearly you're setting the page [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry). If you remove that you'll see the original page layout (more whitespace around the text block)...

Comment: You can also add the `showframe` option to `geometry` package loading in order to see the margins and page setup

Comment: If I remove the `geometry` package, then I wouldn't have a `3cm` left margin, which I want.

Comment: How can I get the 3cm left margin while the `fancy` package also used?

Comment: @MuhammadAbdulrasool: I don't see that `fancyhdr` changes the margins. Comment the `\pagestyle{fancy}` command out and you will see that the margins are the same. In fact, I think that `fancyhdr` can't  change the margins really!

Comment: There's also a clear warning by `fancyhdr` that `headheight` is too small and should be set to at least `17pt`. Setting `headheight=18pt` in `geometry` options removes this issue

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - I tried to set the `headheight`but nothing happen, `\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=2cm,headheight=18pt]{geometry}`

Comment: @MuhammadAbdulrasool: What do you expect to happen at all? I just printed your document (with the 'showframe' enabled) and I get exactly the margins you desired, also the very large parindent is there

Comment: The problem is the header is too small, my supervisor is waiting for me now so I need to fix this problem immediately to send the thesis,.

Comment: @MuhammadAbdulrasool: You have to increase the top margin then -- all of this has nothing to do with `fancyhdr` itself! That package occupies the header but does not set its height!

Comment: try `\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=2cm,includehead]{geometry} `

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When you set the margins with `geometry`, the header and footer are not taken into consideration by default. You have to explicitly add the `includehead` and `includefoot` options for that.

Here's a better version of your code; note that sans serif bold small caps is not available with Computer Modern fonts (and I suggest using just one layer of emphasis, so either bold or small caps, not both).

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 14pt,oneside]{extreport}
\usepackage[
  top=2cm,
  bottom=2cm,
  left=3cm,
  right=2cm,
  headheight=17pt, % as per the warning by fancyhdr
  includehead,includefoot,
  heightrounded, % to avoid spurious underfull messages
]{geometry} 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all fields
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
%\fancyhead[R]{\bfseries\sffamily\thepage}
\fancyfoot[C]{\bfseries\sffamily\thepage}
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\bfseries\sffamily\leftmark}}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{% for the chapter start pages
  \fancyhf{}% clear all fields
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \fancyfoot[C]{\bfseries\sffamily\thepage}%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Bla bla}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Don't issue `\sloppy`. Your aim is to avoid problems in paragraph formatting, but this is not the solution as it allows very bad paragraphs.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. for the problems in paragraph formating, what should I use instead of `sloppy` ?

Comment: @MuhammadAbdulrasool Fix them in the final version; usually a careful rewriting is sufficient. Do you really need 14pt?

Comment: This is exactly what I mean, that the header and footer are not included in margins.

Comment: Yes I do, the standard style for thesis in my college is to use 14pt font size.

Comment: This is a wonderful solution I am using. I wonder why the bottom margin is not really precise (1.8 cm instead of the required 2, as measured from the `showframe` box). Indeed, it doesn't seem to be gradually adjustable (asking for 2.1 cm provides 2.3 cm for that measure).

Comment: @Andrestand I added `heightrounded` so the text height contains an integral number of lines. Not so important when one-sided printing is used, but decisive for two-sided output. If your institution is so fussy with rulers, then you need to do the computation yourself, adjusting the baseline skip.